# Process XML message using PostAsync from IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, soap, httpclient

I had a problem to process soapEnvelopeXml document using **PostAsync** method from **IHttpClientFactory**.
This is what I was trying to do :

```
var soapEnvelopeXml = ObjectToXMLDocumentConverter.ObjectAsXmlDocument(object);
var content = new StringContent(soapEnvelopeXml.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content);
```

This was producing 400 Bad Request error.

Answer (score 1):

What I find as a solution to my problem is direct usage of **SOAP string** instead of first converting it to XML message :

```
 var soapString = ObjectToSoapRequestConverter.ObjectSoapStringRequest(object);
  using (var client = clientFactory.CreateClient())
     {
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(...);
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(...);
         var content = new StringContent(soapString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                 using (var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content))
                 {
                     var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ...                    
                 }
      }
```